# Why a string in the form ####e##### is converted to float when inserted into sqlite database?

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I am facing the following issue when working with a sqlite database and python.
This happens also with an external program such as SQLiteStudio, so it is not python.
Suppose to have a table containing a column of type string.
If you enter an entry to that column such as 43234e4324 (so, all the entries of the kind ####e##### give the issue), the value stored in the database is converted to inf!
For sure, since e may be interpreted as the exponent, it would make sense if the column is of type float, but it is string!

Here is a working example:

```
import sqlite3
a = sqlite3.connect('test.sqlite')
a.execute('CREATE TABLE test (p STRING)')
a.execute('INSERT INTO test (p) VALUES (03242e4444)')
a.commit()
b = a.execute('SELECT p FROM test')
b.fetchall()
```

and you get [(inf,)]...
If you insert a different value without the 'e' you would get the correct string.

I want to enter a string like 43243e3423 without it being converted. How can I do this?

Comment: If it's supposed to be a string, put it in quotes.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation

Comment: I have tried with
    a.execute('INSERT INTO test (p) VALUES (\'03242e4444\')')
but still got the same error!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A number with an `e` in it is a floating point number in [exponential notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation). `43234e3423` is the notation for 43234x10<sup>3423</sup>. Since that's far too big to be stored as a floating point number, you get `inf`.

To enter strings, you should put them in quotes.

```
a.execute('INSERT INTO test (p) VALUES ("03242e4444")')
```

The other problem is that there's no `STRING` datatype. An unrecognized datatype is treated as `NUMERIC`, so even if you put quotes around the value, it gets converted as if it were a number. Use `TEXT` instead.

```
a.execute('CREATE TABLE test (p TEXT)')
```

Comment: I've updated the answer. The other problem is the `STRING` datatype.